# Importing grid layer from CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import, vector-grid, polygon-creation

In QGIS, I used the `Create grid` function to produce a grid. It produces an attribute table that looks something like that :

[image: grid attribute table]

Now, let say I have a CSV file with the same attributes.

| id | left | top | right | bottom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "1" | -79.765324266 | 62.582465701 | -77.765324266 | 60.582465701 |
| "2" | -79.765324266 | 60.582465701 | -77.765324266 | 58.582465701 |
| "3" | -79.765324266 | 58.582465701 | -77.765324266 | 56.582465701 |
| "4" | -79.765324266 | 56.582465701 | -77.765324266 | 54.582465701 |
| "5" | -79.765324266 | 54.582465701 | -77.765324266 | 52.582465701 |

How can I import my CSV in QGIS and recreate the grid based on attributes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you import your CSV as a delimited text layer, you could use the ["Geometry by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool on the layer to construct the polygons with this expression:

```sql
make_rectangle_3points(
    make_point("left", "top"),
    make_point("right", "top"),
    make_point("right", "bottom")
)
```

[image]

*EPSG:4326*

The polygon layer will inherit any attributes from the CSV layer.

Comment: One other alternative, depending on what you prefer, is to add a column to your .csv to generate a WKT "Linestring (left bottom,right top)" and open the .csv with the WKT column as geometry source (this will generate a line grid).

Comment: Sounds like a valid answer to me, @Kasper

Answer (score 10):

A PyQGIS solution.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from csv import reader
from ast import literal_eval
from os.path import normpath
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import edit, QgsProject, QgsField, QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY, QgsFeature, QgsVectorLayer

# a path to the CSV file
path_to_csv = normpath("C:/Users/taras/Python Scripts/grid.csv")

# opening the CSV file as a list
with open(path_to_csv, mode='r') as file:
    reader = reader(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    list_ = list(reader)
 
raw_data = [] # a holder for raw data
keys_list = list_[0] # only field names
values_list = list_[1:] # only field values 

# function for getting rid of quotes, perhaps quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE is better to use
def no_quotes(x):
    try:
        return literal_eval(x)
    except:
        return x

# converting each record to its proper data type
values_list_ = [list(map(lambda value: no_quotes(value), values)) for values in values_list]

# zipping a key with a corresponding value
for values in values_list_:
    raw_data.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))

# preparing an empty polygon layer for the output
output_crs = "epsg:4326"
polygon_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Polygon?crs={output_crs}", "grid", "memory")

# nesting new fields into the output layer
data_provider = polygon_layer.dataProvider()
data_provider.addAttributes([
    QgsField('id', QVariant.Int),
    QgsField('left', QVariant.Double),
    QgsField('top', QVariant.Double),
    QgsField('right', QVariant.Double),
    QgsField('bottom', QVariant.Double)
    ])
polygon_layer.updateFields()

# editing the polygon layer
with edit(polygon_layer):
    # looping over each record in the raw data
    for record in raw_data:
        # providing fields for each feature
        feat = QgsFeature(polygon_layer.fields())
        # creating four vertices for each polygon feature
        p1 = QgsPointXY(record['left'], record['bottom'])
        p2 = QgsPointXY(record['left'], record['top'])
        p3 = QgsPointXY(record['right'], record['top'])
        p4 = QgsPointXY(record['right'], record['bottom'])
        points = [p1,p2,p3,p4]
        # setting feature's geometry
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points]) 
        feat.setGeometry(geom)
        # filling feature with attributes
        feat.setAttributes(list(record.values()))
        # adding feature
        data_provider.addFeatures([feat])
polygon_layer.updateExtents()

# adding polygon layer to the map canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(polygon_layer)
```

*Input:*

[image: input]

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the *output* that will look like this:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you can generate additional columns in your .csv you can generate a WKT string (POLYGON) column directly in the .csv:

```
POLYGON(left bottom, left top, right top, right bottom, left bottom)
```

and then open the .csv with the WKT column as geometry source.

Note to expand the answer beyond your specific case if you generate a Line grid with QGIS rather than a Place lygon grid.

Then either `bottom = top` or `left = right` and you can use LINESTRING type WKT

```
Linestring (left bottom,right top)
```

Answer (score 6):

After importing your CSV, you can use the ["Geometry by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool with the following expressions.

If the grid contains squares, you can use:

```sql
make_square(
    make_point("left", "top"),
    make_point("right", "bottom")
)
```

If not squares, you can also use:

```sql
make_polygon( 
    make_line( -- outer ring
       make_point("left", "top"),
       make_point("right", "top"),
       make_point("right" "bottom"),
       make_point("left", "bottom")
    )
)
```