# Adding vectors (segments) connecting pairs of points from CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, csv, polyline-creation, xy, points-to-line

a) Given: In QGIS 3.28 I have two sets of points: Points M and Points N (See embedded image), given by their coordinates in a CSV file.

b) Required: A set of vectors (or segments) connecting the pairs of points M and N
(i.e., Vector V1 connecting M1 with N1, Vector V_n connecting M_n with N_n, and so on).

c) What I have tried:

- As a beginner, I could create two layers (with their shapefiles); one for points M and the other for points N.
  However, I don't know how to create a layer of vectors/segments.
- I thought of creating a new shape layer (with the intention of defining lines within it), but it couldn't be created based on the CSV file.
- I searched for similar issues. Some suggested using "PointsToPath", but this is useful in case one wants to connect all given points together as a sequence, which is not what I want here.

How can I do that?

[image: A simlified sample of the CSV file that I have]

Comment: Maybe you will find some inspiration here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448290/importing-grid-layer-from-csv-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks @Taras. Checking.

Comment: @Taras Actually yes! However, as I mentioned in a comment to Babel (the answer below), I saw yesterday, but it didn't work for me and I didn't know why then, so I sropped it. In fact, the problem was merely with the CRS being used! Though, I believe this thread is still useful, as it's very well explained, plus the query here is more simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the csv to QGIS using Data Source Manager > Delimited Text tab.
Be sure to check the preview, especially the field types and change them if necessary. Coordinate values should be of type Decimal, ID of type Integer.

*You can add a Geometry definition to create at least one of the points M or N, but this is not necessary. Use EPSG:4326 for Geoemtry CRS and the coordinates you have.*

[Create a virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) (Menu Layer > Create Layer > New Virtual Layer) with this query, where `points` is the name of the loaded csv layer:

```sql
select make_line (make_point (x_M, y_M), make_point(x_N, y_N)) as GEOM
from points
```

*The virtual layer creates three lines, based on the three rows of the csv:*
[image]

If you want, export/save this layer as Geopackage, Shapefile etc. If you want to get the points, run `Menu Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract Vertices` on the virtual layer.

*Loading csv to QGIS:*
[image]

Comment: That's awesome! It worked. Marked as solved. BTW, I saw a similar q&a yesterday: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395241/creating-multiple-separate-vector-lines-from-list-of-coordinate-pairs-in-qgis and I tried it, but it didn't work, because oI didn't fix the Geometry CRS as you highlighted above, so I thought I was far and ignored it:) Thanks a lot Babel.